# Bind mdTabs of angular material text to a scope property

Tags: angularjs, scope, bind, angular-material

I'm using material mdTabs. I'm trying to update the tab text with a length of an array. I want this number to updated when the length of the array is changed.

On the first load it works fine, but once the array changes, the tab doesn't being updated.

```
<md-tabs  md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom >
                <md-tab label="Selected Content({{selectedContent.length}})">
                    <md-content class="md-padding">

                        </md-content>
                </md-tab>            
</md-tabs>
```

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

View File:

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom flex>
<md-tab label="Selected Content 1 ({{data.length}})">
  <md-content class="md-padding" flex style="background-color:red">
    <md-button ng-click="add()">Push</md-button>
    <md-button ng-click="remove()">Pop</md-button>
    {{data}}
  </md-content>
</md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

JS FIle:(Controller)

```
$scope.data = [];
$scope.i = 0;

$scope.add = function(){
    $scope.data.push($scope.i);
    $scope.i++;
}

$scope.remove = function(){
    $scope.data.pop();
    $scope.i--;
}
```

Try this code. It is working fine. See the below link for working example.
http://codepen.io/next1/pen/aNRMam